# how to import a txt file into a JTable and make the first column auto increment according to the number of lines of the file

Tags: java, swing, file, jtable

i'm doing some java coding and i have to import a file into a Jtable that has 4 columns while my file has 3 (separated by whitespaces, i need the first column of each line to be auto increment, here is my code:

```
try {
    FileReader  files = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(files);                
    String line = null; 
    String tokens[] = null;
    while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) { 
        tokens = line.split("\\p{javaWhitespace}+");
        //System.out.println( Arrays.toString( tokens ));
        model.addRow(tokens);
    } 
}
```

and this is what I'm getting :
[image]

and this is my file :
[image: file]

Comment: Please show us your attempt to do this. For my money, I'd create a `Vector<Object>` and then add an int first, then each item in the tokens array, and then add the Vector to the table model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an additional token to the front of your data. This is easiest using a Vector and not an array. The first item in the vector is your row index, the next itmes are filled from your tokens array. For example:

```
try {
    FileReader  files = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(files);                
    String line = null; 
    String tokens[] = null;
    int count = 0;
    while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) { 
        tokens = line.split("\\p{javaWhitespace}+");
        Vector<Object> row = new Vector<>();
        row.add(count);
        count++;
        for (String text: tokens) {
            row.add(text);
        }
        model.addRow(row); // add the Vector, not the tokens array
    } 
}
```

There are other ways, including extending the table model such that it automatically does this, and these may need to be done, depending on your needs -- for example, are the rows to renumber if one row is deleted or added during the running of the program? If so the logic needs to be *within* the table model.